# QGroundControl build with Qt on Mac

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qgroundcontrol

Hello I cloned the repository of QGround Control (open source application [link](https://github.com/Abelio-farm-monitoring/qgroundcontrol),
However the version on Github does not compile with Qt, I use version 5.12.6 as specified on the support ([link](https://dev.qgroundcontrol.com/master/en/getting_started/)), the build environment I chose is Destop Qt 5.12.6 clang 64bit here are the errors (I think the errors come from a bad installation or set-up of Qt Creator):

```
Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qvariant.h:399: error: definition of implicit copy assignment operator for 'Private' is deprecated because it has a user-declared copy constructor [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-copy]
        inline Private(const Private &other) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
               ^
```

Please note that I am using MacOs 11.2.3.

The version of Qt creator: 4.10.2 based on 5.13.2

Comment: does `QGroundControl` support qt 5.13 .. did you try with supported version .. I think 5.10

Comment: yes i tried for the version of Qt it's version 5.12.6, this version compiles for the release 3.5.6 but not for the new versions should i ask for a review ?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of things going on here:

1. You are compiling with a more recent compiler, in which various previously-kosher practices (like declaring a copy-constructor without also declaring an assignment-operator) are now considered deprecated, causing the compiler to issue a warning about them.
2. You're compiling with `-Werror`, which causes the compiler to treat all warnings as errors.  This, in conjunction with Qt headers that have not been updated to be latest-and-greatest-compiler-friendly and therefore produce warnings, is [causing your compile to error out](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/05/22/werror-is-not-your-friend/).

I think the easy fix is to find where in your project-settings it is that `-Werror` is being specified, and remove it; then the code should (hopefully) compile successfully despite any warnings the compiler might emit.